# How do I setup for using PROC SCAPROC on ZOS

Tags: sas

After reading many links on SCAPROC, I could not find any links that mentioned about SCAPROC usage on zOS. Can someone please help me by giving me a few examples for SCAPROC usage on zOS? I have currently pointed a *variable* used with the RECORD keyword to a DD name in the JCL as below:

```
PROC SCAPROC; RECORD DDNAME;
```

But,

```
PROC SCAPROC; WRITE
```

is giving errors such as

```
REQUESTED DATALENGTH (51200) IS INVALID FOR LRECL (622537396) AND/OR BLKSIZE (0)
```

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: That looks like a portion of your code. Can you include the full code and log?

Comment: That's pretty much what PROC SCAPROC looks like, from what I've seen.  @OP - I don't know much about zOS, but my best guess is you need to define `DDNAME` perhaps with a filename statement to have appropriate lrecl/blksize first?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the correct record and blocksize in your JCL.

Something like:

```
LRECL=51200,BLKSIZE=204800
```

On your DDNAME statement.